# What's the easiest and quickest way to get the MIME/Media/Content type of a given URL?

Tags: php, mime-types, content-type, file-type, media-type

So I'm going to transfer a file from a remote server to my server but before I transfer it I want to know what sort of file it is.  If it's an HTML file I'll deal with it in a certain way, if it's a PDF file I'll deal with it in a different way, and if, for instance, it's an exe file, I don't want to transfer it at all.

All I've got to go on is a URL.  Now if that URL is explicit (i.e. http://example.com/file.pdf) it's not a problem, I can just check the file extension and we're sorted.  However, I might only be given a URL such as http://example.com and it could be anything.

Is it possible to check (with PHP) what type of file it is before I download it?

**Edit:** I will be using cURL to transfer the file, but I believe that [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) can only be called after the file has been transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PHP [get_headers](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function, e.g.:

```
$h = get_headers("http://google.com", $format = 1);
$content_type = $h["Content-Type"];
// and now parse what you want from array
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an fopen handle, you can then call [stream_get_meta_data()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) on it.